# How are variable values stored in C?

Tags: c, variables, reference

Let's say I have the following C code:

```
int x= 4;
int y = x;
printf("x:%d,y:%d\n",x,y);
```

X now references the memory location where the '4' is stored and prints as 4. y references x so it will also print 4. So why is it that when I change the value of x, eg `x=6;`, y doesn't get changed also? I must be misunderstanding something. Is it the same for all languages?

I couldn't find an answer to my question anywhere (probably because of poor wording).

Comment: Some variables are done via references, other via values.  Numbers are done via values, so each thing is stored separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is completely wrong.

When you write `int x = 4;`, the `x` represents an actual memory location on the stack, that then gets filled with the value `4`. `x` is irrevocably linked with that piece of memory - when `x` goes out of scope the memory also disappears.

When you write `int y = x;` again `y` represents an actual piece of memory. It does not 'refer' to `x`, instead, the *contents* of `x` are *copied* into `y`.

> Is it the same for all languages?

No, different languages can and do have completely different semantics. However the way C does it is usually called *value semantics*.

Comment: The confusing part about talking about this is that sometimes the "value" being copied in an assignment *is* a reference.

Comment: @Alexander C does not have references. It has pointers, but as long as you keep the concepts "the address of X" and "X itself" separate it shouldn't really be that confusing.

Comment: @orlp: Pointers provide references. The C standard says so (C 2018 6.2.5 20). Please do not confuse the new feature in C++ that it adopted the term “reference” for with past and ongoing uses of the term in C.

Answer (score 5):

`y` never references `x`. The assignment operator, `=`, copies values. `x` is just a value of `4`, of `int` type. `int y = x` is assigning the current value of x to y, copying it in the process.

To behave like you're describing, `y` would need to be a pointer to an int, `int *`, and it would be assigned the address of `x`, like so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x = 4;
    int *y = &x;
    
    
    printf("before: x: %d, y: %d\n", x, *y);
    
    x = 123; // modify x
    
    printf("after:  x: %d, y: %d\n", x, *y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> X now references the memory location where the '4' is stored

No, 4 isn't stored anywhere, it's a parameter to a `mov`. `x` has its own memory location that holds an integer value, in this case 4.

> y references x

No, `y` also has its own memory location that stores an integer, also in this case 4.

> So why is it that when I change the value of x, eg x=6;, y doesn't get changed

They're both different memory locations, changing one has no impact on the other.

Answer (score 1):

> *y references x so it will also print 4.*

This is your basic misunderstanding. The `y` variable is **not** a reference; it is a variable of type `int` that has no *implicit* connection to `x` whatsoever. When the `int y = x;` initialization is performed, the current ***value*** in the `x` variable is ***copied*** to the `y` variable.

Any subsequent changes to the values of either `x` or `y` will not affect the value of the other (unless an explicit reassignment from one to the other is performed).

> *Is it the same for all languages?*

Well, I'm not even going to *attempt* to answer for "all languages!" However, a language that is, in some ways, 'close' to C is C++. For the code you have shown, the behaviour (and the explanation above) will be the same for C and C++. However, in C++, you *can* define a variable as a reference!

Simply adding the `&` character in its declaration will make `y` a **reference variable**; in so doing, changing `x` will also change the displayed value of `y`. Try compiling the following code (be sure to use a C++ compiler) and testing it as is and using the commented-out line, instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 4;
//  int y = x;   // Using this line, the value of "y" won't change...
    int& y = x;  // ... but adding the "&" makes "y" a REFERENCE.
    printf("x:%d,y:%d\n", x, y); // x:4,y:4
    x = 6;
    printf("x:%d,y:%d\n", x, y); // x:6,y:6 (with the "&") or x:6,y:4 (without the "&")
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For these two variables

```
int x= 4;
int y = x;
```

the compiler allocates their own memory extents with sizes that correspond to the size of an object of the type `int`, The value of the variable `x` that is the value stored in the memory extent allocated  for the variable `x` is used to initialize the variable `y` that is its memory extent.

So if you when write for example

```
x = 6;
```

then  the integer constant `6` is stored in the memory extent allocated for the variable `x`. The variable `y` will stay unchanged.

If to speak about references then in C pointers provide references to entities (functions or objects).

If you will write for example

```
int *px = &x;
```

then the pointer `px` provide a reference to the variable `x`.

So pointers are used in the mechanism of passing objects to functions by reference. Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *px )
{
    *px = 10;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 1;
    
    printf( "Before calling f() x = %d\n", x );
    
    f( &x );
    
    printf( "After  calling f() x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling f() x = 1
After  calling f() x = 10
```

In the program the variable `x` declared in main is passed to the function `f` by reference through a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same for all languages. Is it the same for C-style languages, like C++ and such? Normally, yes.

Importantly, `x` doesn't reference a "memory location". It just represents an object (in C parlance, meaning "thing that you can change and pass around") that has a particular value. When compiled that `x` might be stored in memory, in a register, or optimized out and eliminated entirely.

For example:

```c
int x = 1;
int y = x + 1;
int z = 4;

printf("x:%d,y:%d\n",x,y);
```

Here `y` will be `2`, that can be determined at compile time, `x` will be `1`, and `z` doesn't matter so it might even get deleted. `y` isn't computed based on `x`, it's computed based on *static analysis* of the code where the compiler rightfully asserts that it can only ever be `2`, so the `x` factor is optimized out.

When you change `y` you're changing a separate thing, it has no effect on `x` unless you *explicitly* make that assignment.

This is not true in a language like C++ where references exist, as those are like variable aliases:

```cpp
int& y = x; // Same as `x`, where `y` is just another name for same
```

Note that this is limited as well, like if `int y = x + 2` you can't use references, as you're not referencing a variable. That's an *expression*.

In some languages an assignment like this is treated more in the mathematical sense, as in `y` is *always* `x + 2` depending on whatever value `x` has at that moment. [Functional programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) tend to employ this model, but the specifics differ considerably.

What you're probably asserting is "Do variables work like this in [imperative programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming)?" where the answer is *normally* yes.